# Show that no choice of numbers $a$ and $b$ can make $ax + by = (3,0,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Show that no choice of numbers $a$ and $b$ can make $ax + by = (3,0,0)$ when $x = (3,-1,0)$ and $y = (0,1,5)$.

The only materials in the chapter talked about are:

- Vector Space Operations
- Standard Basis
- Coordinates of a vector $x$
- Components of a vector $x$

I don't think that the vector $v=(3,0,0)$ has a unique linear combination of coordinates with respect to the standard basis with how $x$ and $y$ are defined. I also don't think stating this is "rigorous" enough of an answer. Is there a better (clearer) way I can show that the above statement is true?

How can I show that the statement is true from a geometric point of view?

Comment: $\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 5 \end{vmatrix}=-15\ne0$ so they're linearly independent

Comment: can you explain the significance of the determinant $\neq 0$  and being linearly independent?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Properties) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Alternative_method_using_determinants) and my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$ax+by = a(3, -1, 0) + b(0, 1, 5) =(3,0,0)$ gives you the system of equations
$$ 3a = 3 , \, -a+b = 0, \, 5b = 0. $$
Can you go on from here?

Comment: Then $a = \frac{3}{3} = 1$, $b = 1$, but $5(1) = 0$ is false. Then the conclusion is that we can't make $(3,0,0)$ from any given $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Answer (score 1):

You may not have learned this yet, but
$n$ vectors in $ \mathbb {R} ^{n}$ are linearly independent if and only if

the determinant of the matrix formed by taking the vectors as its columns is non-zero.

In your particular case, that matrix has a form (upper triangular) that makes it very easy to compute

the determinant (simply multiply the diagonal entries):

$\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 5 \end{vmatrix}=-15\ne0,$ so they're linearly independent.

Comment: also, the $3\times3$ determinant is the scalar [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) of the vectors in its columns, thus zero iff the vectors are coplanar